# Objective-C singleton GCD - [self alloc] or [Class alloc]

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I was looking at modern patterns of Objective-C to create singletons after the introduction of `instance`

from: [Create singleton using GCD's dispatch_once in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c)

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^
    {
        sharedInstance = [self new];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

And I was wondering why not use [MyFunnyClass new] as below?

```
@implementation MyFunnyClass
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^
    {
        sharedInstance = [MyFunnyClass new];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Or if it's the same?

(Ref: http://nshipster.com/instancetype/)

Edit: the answers given at [Why use [ClassName alloc] instead of [[self class] alloc]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559763/why-use-classname-alloc-instead-of-self-class-alloc) are not related to this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use \[ClassName alloc\] instead of \[\[self class\] alloc\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559763/why-use-classname-alloc-instead-of-self-class-alloc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, in this case, to use `[self new]` instead of `[MyClass new]`, and to use `static id sharedInstance` instead of `static MyClass *sharedInstance`, is because you can just copy and paste the entire method without editing it. Nothing in the method is specific to the class it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

See [Why use [ClassName alloc] instead of [[self class] alloc]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559763/why-use-classname-alloc-instead-of-self-class-alloc)

Also, the convention is to use alloc/init, not new. See [alloc, init, and new in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330963/alloc-init-and-new-in-objective-c)